# dynamic class select in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a function in jquery using handlebars. where name of html and class where it has to be appended will be pass dynamically.

Basically i need something like this :

```
var pageTemplate="";
function addTempl(){
var renderedPage = pageTemplate(pageName);
    $("#Class_id").empty();
    $("#Class_id").append( renderedPage );
}
```

this Class_name and pageName will be dynamically passed to this function from another main function where it will be called.

Issue is i can pass pageName as it is javascript thing but how to do same for Class_name. beacuse if I append '#' and "" it is not coming.

please let me know if my problem is still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

class is denoted by `.` and id is denoted by `#`

**updated**

```
$("#"+Class_id).empty();
$("#"+Class_id).append( renderedPage );
```

in one line

```
 $("#"+Class_id).empty().append( renderedPage );
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion it is class_id and so #. but what i need is class_id is not static. when i will pass say class_id as class1,class2 it should accordingly append html in the main html file

Answer (score 0):

Try this in order to select class use dot `.`

```
   $("#"+Class_id).empty();
   $("#"+Class_id).append( renderedPage );
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. plz see above i have corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to use dynamic selector based on passed parameter. You can do something like:

```
function doSomething(className) {
  var selector =  "#" + className; // # for id, . for class
  $(selector).empty();
  $(selector).append(something);
}
```

Optimized version would be:

```
function doSomething(className) {
  var x =  $("#" + className); // # for id, . for class
  x.empty();
  x.append(something);
}
```

Optimized = you look for the element in DOM only once